# show text and a button in dojo EnhancedGrid

Tags: button, dojo, grid

I have a dojo Enhanced Grid and I'm using formatter to display a button in one of the columns

```
 {field: '_item', name: 'Update Data', formatter: dojo.hitch(context, this.getUpdateData), width: '165px' },




getUpdateData: function(rowItem) {      
        var button = new dijit.form.Button({
            label: '<img src="/public/img/icon_texteditor.png" height="19px" width="19px"/>',
            onClick: function(){
                alert('hi');
            }
        });         
        return button;              
    }
```

This works well.  The button is correctly rendered and when I click on it, it correctly shows the alert dialog.  What I'd like to do is show some text/label and then the button in the grid cell.  I've tried creating a div in the formatter and tried adding the button to the div:

```
getUpdateData: function(rowItem) { 
        var divNode = dojo.create("div", { innerHTML: rowItem.someText });
        var button = new dijit.form.Button({
            label: '<img src="/public/img/icon_texteditor.png" height="19px" width="19px"/>',
            onClick: function(){
                alert('hi');
            }
        });

        button.placeAt(divNode);
        return divNode.innerHTML;
    }
```

Even though it renders it correctly (where the text is shown before the button in the table) , when I click on the button nothing happens.  The onClick event handler is not called.

My question is: how can show the some text+ a button in a grid cell.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
getUpdateData: function(rowItem) {   
 var cpane = new dojox.layout.ContentPane (
        content: rowItem.someText;
 });

 var button = new dijit.form.Button({
            label: '<img src="/public/img/icon_texteditor.png" height="19px"  width="19px"/>',
            onClick: function(){
                alert('hi');
            }
        });


 button.placeAt (cpane);
 return cpane;
}
```